# Is there a way to play Call of Duty: Black Ops on LAN without an internet connection?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops

Is there any way i can play black ops (PC) on LAN with my friend without Internet Connection.

EDIT: Even if solution requires Internet, solution must not connect to black ops servers. I just wanted to play with my friend using hamachi or any other mean

Comment: What platform are you using? PC/XBox/PS3?

Comment: I am using PC..

Comment: I hope you're not asking because you and your friend want to use pirated copies of Black Ops. Asking questions about how to perform illegal activities is against our site policy, as explained in the FAQ.

Comment: We don't have that speed internet connections, currently we are only able to play counter strike and laggy ghost recon advance war fighter 2

Comment: Playing over Hamachi won't help much. If anything, it will cause more lag.

Answer (score 5):

To authenticate the user account, each user has to have an internet connection. Then setup a dedicated LAN server on the net and connect to this by using the in-game console (look it up on the net on how to enable the console):

```
/connect <ip>:<port>
```

you can fetch your local-ip of the server PC by looking it up via command line

```
c:\ipconfig
```

it could be something like 192.168.0.3, depending on your router settings.
Then just type

`/connect 192.168.0.3` (if standard port, you may omit it).

Answer (score 0):

Treyarch has said on their Twitter (@pcdev) that the PC version requires all LAN players to have an active Internet connection. http://twitter.com/pcdev/status/23106835501

Comment: But it does not tell how.